# Show $(A\cup B) \setminus A = B \setminus (A\cap B) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Show $(A\cup B) \setminus A = B \setminus (A\cap B) $:

My reasoning:
LHS: $$x\in((A\cup B)\setminus A)$$ 
$$\equiv x\in(A\cup B) \land x\notin A$$
$$\equiv(x\in A \land x\notin A) \lor(x\in B \land x\notin A)$$
$$\equiv x\in B \land x\notin A$$
$$\equiv x\in(B\setminus A)$$
And I know the final result is equivalent to $B\setminus(A\cap B)$ because I can show that:

$$x \in (B\setminus(A\cap B))$$
$$\equiv x\in B \land x\notin(A\cap B)$$
$$\equiv x\in B \land \lnot(x\in A \land x\in B)$$
$$\equiv x\in B\land(x\notin A\lor x\notin B)$$
$$\equiv(x\in B \land x\notin A)\lor (x\in B\land x\notin B)$$
$$\equiv(x\in B \land x\notin A)$$
$$\equiv x \in (B \setminus A)$$
But is there a better way to show the sets are equivalent? And btw I'm not sure if I actually proved anything in the second part by starting from what I should have proved from: $x\in (B\setminus(A\cap B))$ and getting to $x \in (B \setminus A)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(A \cup B) \setminus A = (A \cup B) \cap A^c = B \cap A^c$.

$B \setminus (A \cap B) = B \cap (A \cap B)^c = B \cap (A^c \cup B^c) = B \cap A^c$.

Here is an approach using indicator functions:

The indicator function $1_C$ denotes the function $1_C(x) = \begin{cases} 0,& x \notin C \\ 1,& x \in C \end{cases}$.

Note that 
\begin{eqnarray}
1_{(A \cup B) \setminus A} &=&  \max(0, 1_{A \cup B} - 1_A) =
\max(0, \max(1_A,1_B)-1_A) \\
&=& \max(0,\max(0, 1_B-1_A)) = \max(0, 1_B-1_A) \\
&=& 1_{B\setminus A}
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
1_{B \setminus (A \cap B)} &=& \max(0, 1_B-1_{A \cap B})= \max(0, 1_B-\min(1_A,1_B))\\
&=& \max(0, 1_B+\max(-1_A,-1_B)) = \max(0,\max(1_B-1_A,0)) \\
&=& \max(0, 1_B-1_A) = 1_{B\setminus A}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

$(A\cup B)\setminus A= (A\cup B) \cap A^c= (A\cap A^c) \cup(B\cap A^c)=B\cap A^c$

and

$B\setminus(A\cap B)= B \cap (A\cap B)^c= B\cap (A^c \cup B^c)=B\cap A^c$